# How am I supposed to extract the shape(s) out of this vector tracing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I am a beginner and don't know what is this, may be a compound (if that's what its called)?

I am trying to extract those shapes but do not know what and how to do with this one.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your layers panel?

Comment: Here: https://youtu.be/UvnN-wVg4sM. I tried the clipping mask release but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

There *appears* to be a clipping mask.

Select the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) and click-drag on one of the *bottom corners* of the artboard -- being sure to NOT drag over any of the artwork you see.

A rectangle will probably highlight. Simply hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key twice to remove it.

---

Option 2...

Select all. From the menu choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Release`

You should then see your artwork and a bounding rectangle around the artboard. You can delete that rectangle, but even if you don't it will stop acting as a mask.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Here: https://youtu.be/UvnN-wVg4sM. I tried the clipping mask release but nothing happened.

Comment: and another attempt, another video: https://youtu.be/fLTg-EPRyVc

Comment: There are **multiple** clipping masks. Your best bet is to review the [Adobe Help Topic on Clipping Masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)